# How to access a field on an object that has been passed using an interface, when the interface does not define that field

Tags: dart, types, interface, casting

I am using an external API, which I cannot modify and want to access a field on an object that is not defined by its interface.

Interface `IFoo` does not define the field `headers`.
Both `Foo` and `Bar` implement `IFoo` and both have an additional field `headers` of type `String`.

This is working in Dart, but is far from elegant:

```dart
void doSomething (IFoo data) {
    String headers;
    if (data is Foo) {
      headers = data.headers;
    } else if (data is Bar) {
      headers = data.headers;
    }
}
```

This does **not** work in dart:

```dart
void doSomething (IFoo data) {
    String headers;
    if (data is Foo || data is Bar) {
      headers = data.headers;
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way than the above first example?

Comment: It seems `headers` is a kind of _shared_ property between some types (basically `IFoo`) why not define it in `IFoo`? If it doesn't have to be in `IFoo`, at least it might be possible to do some interface segregation in this case...

Comment: I am not the author of the API and cannot change the interface. I updated the question accordingly. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way than the above first example?

Taking a look at a higher level of the whole picture, the "elegant way" that I'd suggest in this case is following the *[Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle#:%7E:text=In%20the%20field%20of%20software,are%20of%20interest%20to%20them.)*.

It's clear that the declaration of the `headers` property is common for some of the types (such as `Foo` and `Bar`), however, if declaring it in `IFoo` does not make sense (for code design reasons, such as there are other types of `IFoo` don't need to have the `headers` declared), it's still sensible to have a common type for all subtypes that have the `headers` property.

In Dart, using [mixin](https://dart.dev/language/mixins) would be a proper way to achieve it. Example:

```
abstract class IFoo {}

mixin MixinFoo {
  String get headers => 'MixinFoo';
}

class Foo with MixinFoo implements IFoo {
  @override
  String get headers => 'Foo';
}

class Bar with MixinFoo implements IFoo {
  @override
  String get headers => 'Bar';
}
```

Note that `Foo` and `Bar` are still `IFoo` types, additionally, they are `MixinFoo` as well! This means that they have the `headers` property without mixing the logic of being `IFoo`s.

Therefore, you are able to cast the given value, as:

```
void doSomething (IFoo data) {
    String headers;
    MixinFoo? dataMixin = (data is MixinFoo ? data : null) as MixinFoo?;

    // if the data is not a MixinFoo, then dataMixin will be null
    if (dataMixin != null) {
      headers = dataMixin.headers;
    }
}
```

Or (since we are talking about an "elegant way" ):

```
void doSomething (IFoo data) {   
    try {
        String headers;
        final dataMixin = data as MixinFoo;
        headers = dataMixin.headers;
    }
    on TypeError catch(_) {
          // fallback, if the data is not a MixinFoo...
    }
}
```

Any `MixinFoo` type will be castable now, it makes more sense from a code design perspective.